# Count number of items in a Struct?

Tags: swift, struct, count

I have a struct and am using it in many classes. I want to have a way of counting how many structs are initialised in each class (like an array.count) I cannot find anything on it.

```
struct measuredBMInfo {
  var level: Int
  var message: String

init(level: Int, message: String) {
    self.level = level
    self.message = message
  }
}
```

I use the struct as below:

```
// setup pain
let painInfo0 = measuredPainInfo(level: 0, message: "No Pain")
let painInfo1 = measuredPainInfo(level: 1, message: "Mild pain can be ignored")
let painInfo2 = measuredPainInfo(level: 2, message: "Moderate pain that interferes with tasks")
let painInfo3 = measuredPainInfo(level: 3, message: "Moderate pain interferes with concentration")
let painInfo4 = measuredPainInfo(level: 4, message: "Severe pain interferes with basic tasks")
let painInfo5 = measuredPainInfo(level: 5, message: "Worst possible pain bedrest required")
```

I want a count of measuredPainInfo in this case.

Comment: Can you give us some usage examples? It's a little bit unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to get how many structs I have so I can for example fill a table with the correct number of rows.

Comment: Why don't you use an array of those structs? You can then access it's count.

Comment: Actually you – the developer – know exactly the number of instances when setting them up this way ;-)

Comment: Yes but thought when I have to add quite a few classes I could do that automatically. Its good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an array to store structs:

```
var structArray:[measuredBMInfo] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setPainInfo(0, message: "dfsa")
    setPainInfo(1, message: "dsger")
    setPainInfo(2, message: "kh sdfujo")
    setPainInfo(3, message: "sdfasfd")

    print(getStructCount())
}

func setPainInfo(level:Int, message: String){
    let painInfo = measuredBMInfo(level: level, message: message)
    structArray.append(painInfo)
}
```

Get counts of structs using:

```
func getStructCount()->Int{
    return structArray.count
}
```

Comment: Wow I like that. I will try that now.